# Route isn't redirecting me to the correct page. It just shows me the same page but the url changes

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I've made a blog template but I having trouble making the routes. When I click on the link, it should redirect me to the article page. Instead it just redirects me to the same page/same exact location.
Here's my code:

```
<section id="about" class="ts-block" >
    <div id="cards_landscape_wrap-2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        @foreach($blogs as $blog)
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <a href={{route("blogs.show",$blog->slug)}}>
                    <div class="card-flyer"  >
                        <div class="text-box">
                            <div class="image-box ">
                                <img src="{{'/images/blogs/'.$blog->image}}" alt="{{$blog->title}}" class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block" width="100%"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-container">
                                <h6>{{$blog->title}}</h6>
                                <p style="max-width: 18rem;"class="ts-opacity__50">{{Str::limit($blog->description,100)}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                        <span class="text-primary font-weight-bold">Read</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

**BlogController** :

```
public function getArticles()
{
    return view('blog')->with([
        'blogs' => Blog::all(),
    ]);
}
```

**Routes** :

```
Route::get('/blog/', [App\Http\Controllers\BlogController::class, 'index'])->name('blog');
Route::get('blogs/','App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@getArticles')->name('blogs.show');
Route::get('/admin/blog', 'App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@getBlog')->name('admin.blog');
Route::resource('/blog','App\Http\Controllers\BlogController');
```

The routes that supposed to be redirecting me to another page is the 2nd one with `BlogController@getArticles`. The other routes are fine a have no problem.

Can someone kindly show me what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your question is little confusing, because that's the expected result from the code.

You are calling the 'blogs.show' route, which redirects you to the blogs page. If you want to create a seperate page for every article, you can use [Dynamic Rounting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters) in laravel.

All you have to do is:

in web.php:

```
Route::get('blogs/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@getArticle')->name('article.show');
```

and in your controller:

```
public function getArticles($slug)
{

    $article = Blog::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    return view('article')->with([
        'article' => $article,
    ]);
}
```

After that, `<a href={{route("article.show",$blog->slug)}}></a>` will work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the explanation. This actually works but I added 'return view('article.show')'

Answer (score 0):

First, change your route by :

```
Route::get('/blogs/{slug}','App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@getArticles')->name('blogs.show');
```

Then, in your function :

```
public function getArticles($slug)
{
    return view('blog')->with([
        'blogs' => Blog::firstWhere('slug', $slug);
    ]);
}
```

Comment: It's giving me 'Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object'. And is it supposed to be ending with a semi-colon or a comma? 'blogs' => Blog::firstWhere('slug', $slug),

Comment: have you defined the road key in your `blog` model, `public function getRouteKeyName(){ return 'slug'; }` ?? PS. it ends with semi-colon